# C Multithreading for Windows while connection between TCPIP

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, visual-studio

I hope I can explain. I am new in c programming and trying to send and receive binary file using TCPIP. Server should receive multiple files at a time when client send it. I creaded a bat file for send to server. There is no problem if file is 2 or 3 but while trying to send about 5 file sometimes show error. Actually file is not receiving properly. I used

> multithreading Synchronization of `Semaphore` method

The result of receiving side(server) is as follows while printing:

```html
file name (5000.dat)
Invalid argumen(5000.dat) 
completetfile name (5120.dat)
(5120.dat) complete
file name (8192.dat)
(8192.dat) complete
file name (10240.dat)
(10240.dat) complete
```

Some text is misplassed above and each time shows different result. Sometimes reveive and write file properly and sometimes some files can't read.

My code of receving side is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
void fileReceive(void *param);
HANDLE semaphore;
HANDLE threadHandle;
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     if (argc > 1) {
         goto l_param_error;
     }
     WSADATA wsaData; // Contains information about the Windows Sockets implementation
     SOCKET sock0; // creates a socket that is bound to a specific transport    service provider.
     struct sockaddr_in addr;
     struct sockaddr_in client;
     int len;
     SOCKET sock; // creates a socket that is bound to a specific transport service provider

    // Initiates use of the Winsock DLL by a process.
     int error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
     if (error != 0) {
         goto l_WSAIni_error;
     }
     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;// internetwork: UDP, TCP, etc.
     addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
     addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     sock0 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock0 == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            goto l_socket_error;
        }
        // associates a local address with a socket
        if (bind(sock0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
            goto l_bind_error;
        }

        while (1) {

            // places a socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection
            if (listen(sock0, 1) != 0) {
                goto l_socket_conn_setup_error;
            }

            len = sizeof(client);
            // The accept function permits an incoming connection attempt on a socket.
            sock = accept(sock0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
            if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                goto l_error_accpet;
            }
            semaphore = CreateSemaphore(0, 1, 1, 0);

            threadHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthread(&fileReceive, 0, &sock);
            if (threadHandle == 0) {
                printf("Thread handle error");
                return 1;
            }
            CloseHandle(semaphore);
        }

        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

void fileReceive(void *param) {
    int n = 0;
    int sock = *((int *)param);
    unsigned char buf[1];
    unsigned char buff[256] = { 0 };
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    WaitForSingleObject(semaphore, INFINITE);
    // Receive file name
    int recvFile = recv(sock, buff, 255, 0);
    ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, 0);
    if ((recvFile == 0) || (recvFile == -1)) {
        goto l_recv_error;
    }
    fp = fopen(buff, "wb+");
    if (fp != NULL) {

        printf("file name (%s)\n", buff);

        while (n = recv(sock, &buf[0], 1, 0) > 0) {

            size_t written = fwrite(&buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fp);

            if (written != 1) {
                goto l_write_error;
            }
        }
        printf("(%s) complete\n", buff);

    }
    else {
        goto l_fp_error;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    closesocket(sock);
    _endthread();
    CloseHandle(threadHandle);
}
```

Comment: What is the semaphore for?

Comment: How are you expecting the receiver to know where the filename ends and the file data begins? Also, why do you write 256  bytes each time you receive only one? Why is the call to `listen` inside the `while` loop? And I too wonder what purpose you think the semaphore serves.

Comment: The way you communicate sock to the thread is bad - the accepted sock can get overwritten by a new socket before the thread can dereference the pointer.  Also, the usual misuse of TCP  byte stream.  Probably other stuff.

Comment: @MartinJames semphore is the one of the method of multitherading Synchronization

Comment: @Niksankarkee Right, but specifically what does it do here? Why do you think the threads need to be synchronized and in what way do you think the semaphore synchronizes them? For example, why does the thread release the semaphore after calling `recv`?

Comment: ........what David said:)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 256 is i for receive file name because i found in internet there is 255 byte is stander maximum size of file length...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz at the send program first send the file name and then the file so first receive file name and then data

Comment: @MartinJames I did't know about semaphore and while searching in internet multithread shoud be use Synchronization  thats why is use semaphore

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i tried with `Sleep()` also but always the printed sentanse is misplaced so i tried with semaphore but doesn't worked

Comment: @Niksankarkee I don't understand. You tried to do what with `Sleep`? What problem do you think you have exactly? It sounds like you don't understand what thread synchronization is or does. If that's true, you need to learn how to write multithreaded code in C.

Comment: Stop trying to learn more than one concept at a time. Learn windows sockets **first**. Then learn windows threads and their synchronization primitives. Then think about how you could use both together. Because right now it is clear you don't know *either* very well, and that's a recipe for repetitive fail.

Comment: @Niksankarkee Do you *always* send exactly 256 bytes? If so, where the code to read *exactly* 256 bytes? If you send up to 256 bytes, how can the receiver know how many bytes to receive?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think i should have to learn more.. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually now i created structure for sending and reciving file name but this sample is my first tcpip connection program in this program i just wanted to add multithread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have a long list of problems. Bluntly, it seems that you don't understand TCP (it's a byte stream protocol) and it seems that you don't understand what problems thread synchronization solves and how to use it. Given this, you are attempting a task that's way beyond your capabilities and should attempt much simpler tasks first. Start with TCP code that doesn't use threads or threading code that doesn't use TCP so you don't have to get everything right at once.

Here are some of the problems:

1. You pass `&sock` to the thread. But then change the value of `sock`, possibly before the thread can read it.
2. You call `recv` on the TCP connection to get the filename and just assume you'll read all, and only, the filename. TCP has no way to "glue" bytes together into a message. If you want to send and receive messages, you *must* define a message protocol and implement it on top of TCP.
3. Your semaphore doesn't actually do anything. You don't use it to communicate or synchronize anything.
4. You write 256 bytes every time you read 1.

Comment: before this program I created TCPIP program without thread and there is no any problem while sending and receiving one file at a time. And also with this program one file is receive properly. but while receiving multiple file some file is receive and some doesnt thats why i used synchronization. I think i should have to study more about thread. Thank you David for your support

Comment: Your 1 number guess worked i passed `&sock` to the thread and changed the value now with that correction `sock` to the thread there is no misplace of `printf` and multiple file also receiving.. Thank you verymuch

Comment: You should still fix the other bugs!